# What can you use instead of PVC pipe for your dust collector?

Tags: dust-collection

I need to know which kind of piping to use for my dust collector system, before I buy anything now.

Comment: One disadvantage with Schedule 40 PVC is its weight.  I just installed 4" dust ducts using SDR35 pvc piping, the kind used for underground sewer and drain lines and available at home centers.  It is nearly half the weight and can be hung with plastic duct hanger straps screwed into rafters and studs or using toggle bolts to hang it from the ceiling plaster or drywall.

Comment: @Ashlar, and issues with static?

Comment: I have seen arguments that static electricity is not an issue, after all  PVC is an insulator/non conductive.  My installation is new and so far there no dust attraction to the ducts.  I had some old Schedule 40 PVC for years without any static issues.

Comment: See http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/is-pvc-pipe-safe-to-use-for-a-dust-collection-system/1490#1490 for more on static on PVC

Answer (score 5):

For my system I used 4" diameter sheet metal flues for all of the runs with corrugated flexible tubing from the machine to the metal flues.

- It's light weight and easy to hang.
- Readily accommodates blast gates.
- No questions about static build up (readily grounded if the elbows and t's are also metal).
- I used (now get this) duct tape to seal all of the components.
- Negligible loss of sucking power since the surfaces (except for the corrugated tubing) are smooth.

The system has treated me well for the past eight years.

Comment: A friend of mine used the same exact setup in his shop, worked quite well, and a lot easier to work with than PVC.

Answer (score 4):

There are many different kinds and searching for [Dust collection hose](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=dust%20collection%204%20hose&tag=googhydr-20&index=tools&hvadid=28319093841&hvpos=1t3&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10718696249869563120&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_24hzbe6fjm_b) at amazon gives a whole list of stuff.  However I personally have these two in my shop.

[image: hose #1]
<sup>([source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00013UTLQ))</sup>

and

[image: hose #2]
<sup>([source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000223Y0))</sup>

The first is fairly rigid hose and comes in specific pre-cut lengths.  I think 8' or 10'.  It takes a lot to collapse it and is decent for running along the walls and ceiling.  However, if you have a large shop you need a lot of connectors to get from one side to the other.

The second one is cheaper and comes in 50' rolls in a much smaller box, since it can collapse lengthwise.  You run this as far as you need then cut it off.  It is very useful for tools that move around or just needing to move a hose, say as a vacuum cleaner.  It is cheaper and it can tear when cold and brittle.

Hose is much more forgiving than PVC pipe and easier to install because you don't need to run it perfectly straight or put in lots of angles (more angles are bad in dust runs, adds friction and reduces throughput).  But it also needs support and can sag, adding it's own forms of friction.  It is however, much easier to install and later move to new places should your shop configuration change or even when adding new branches.

I have the black hose, but there is also translucent available as well.